# Windows Server 2012 with ASP.net 1.1?

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2012, asp.net-1.1

Is it possible to install ASP.net 1.1 on Windows Server 2012? Have some legacy applications that would be too time consuming/expensive to port at the moment.

I was able to go through a convoluted process on Windows Server 2008 where I assembled an installer package. Not sure if the same thing would work on Server 2012.

Anybody have experience getting this working?

Comment: Have you tried simply setting up assembly binding redirects and trying to run it under 4?  Do you know for a fact there is a breaking change? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/433ysdt1.aspx

Comment: Will you still be asking this question about Windows Server 2022?

Comment: there shouldn't be much to "port" - just have it recompiled and tested.

Comment: John, with an employer that likes the trouble-free system we have, probably. Daniel, there are assemblies we don't have the source code for. I suppose I could try setting it up in .Net 2.0 and see where the problems may lie.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**It is possible to get ASP.NET 1.1 working..**

I've just got a site that depends on ASP.NET 1.1 to run on Server 2012 R2 (so that's IIS 8.5), using the following steps:

- Install "IIS Metabase Compatibility"
- Install the .NET Framework V1.1 and .NET Framework V1.1 SP1
- Enable ASP.NET V1.1 ISAPI Extension - Allow ASP.NET 1.1
- Add IgnoreSection handler To V1.1 Machine.config
- Updated site to use ASP.NET 1.1 Application Pool

> http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/how-to-install-aspnet-11-with-iis-on-vista-and-windows-2008

- Removed the double slash from ISAPI filters.

> https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/25/p/820/4868.aspx#4868

- Copied the machine.config file into the 64 bit framework folder for .net 1.1.

  (although i'm running the app pool in 32 bit mode so perhaps this doesn't apply)

> https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/25/t/820

- Add the following 'handler' overrides to the sites web.config.

(note `system.webServer` element may already exist)

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ASPNET-ISAPI-1.1-WebServiceHandlerFactory" path="*.asmx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv1.1,bitness32" />
        <add name="ASPNET-ISAPI-1.1-SimpleHandlerFactory" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv1.1,bitness32" />
        <add name="ASPNET-ISAPI-1.1-HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-soap" path="*.soap" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv1.1,bitness32" />
        <add name="ASPNET-ISAPI-1.1-PageHandlerFactory" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv1.1,bitness32" />
        <add name="ASPNET-ISAPI-1.1-HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem" path="*.rem" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv1.1,bitness32" />
        <remove name="ASPNET-ISAPI-1.1-AXD" />
        <add name="ASPNET-ISAPI-1.1-AXD" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv1.1,bitness32" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

> http://skills2earn.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/run-aspnet-website-with-net-framework.html

It was this last step that had me guessing for a long time.

Comment: Comment take from a NAA of @Snehil-Jain : *Hi Chris Moutray. Win Server 2008 R2 has IIS version IIS 7.5 not IIS 8.5. Win Server 2012 R2 has IIS version 8.5.
Please make an update.*

Answer (score 5):

.NET 1.1 isn't supported on 2012/Windows 8.

I quote:

> It is not possible to manually install the .NET Framework 1.1 on
>   Windows 8, Windows 8.1 Preview, Windows Server 2012, or Windows Server
>   2012 R2 Preview.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925570.aspx

Comment: As per below answer by Chris, it is possible.  Supported and possible are very different avenues.

Answer (score 2):

I have been banging my head against the wall and trying to solve this for couple days! now it WORKS!!!  I followed all the steps as @Chris Moutray describes above except

at step:

*Copied the machine.config file into the 64 bit framework folder for .net 1.1.
(although i'm running the app pool in 32 bit mode so perhaps this doesn't apply)*

I made a reference to the 32 bit framework by running the following command

```
MKLINK /d c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v1.1.4322 c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322
```

to get the .net 1.1 from the dropdown list as described 
at: http://www.uhleeka.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-install-asp-net-v1-1-with-iis7-on-windows-2008-x64/

Comment: I like this method (creating a symbolic link instead of copying the actual 32-bit folder to the Framework64 folder), nice and clean. In my case, this made the .NET CLR version v1.1.4322 appear in the Application Pool dropdown in IIS.

Comment: By itself this isn't really an answer, it seems like it should be a comment tacked onto Chris Moutray's answer.